# How to choose the zone division for house price estimation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I'm developing a python script that have the aim to predict the house price using a **regression** model (in particular i use a polynomial regression). The features that i use for traint my model are:

- number of room
- squares metres
- number of bathroom
- if there is a terrace
- if there is a balcony
- latitude
- longitude
- zone

The **zone** is a nominal attribute that have about 200 values. This is a important attribute because the price of the house varies depending on the zone, there are a zone more expensive. 
My question is, i should be use only the latitude and longitude or i can use the zone converted in binary for obtain a good regression result?

Comment: personally, I would assign each zone to an integer, and use this numbers as the corresponding zone feature in the trainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there  are three different types of features you can generate from lat/long data: Categories, Clusters, and Distances.

Categories: Turn each record into a category or categories. Categories could be the country, city, point of interest (POI) or a different geo-spatial layer. Generally, this is called Reversed Geocoding (RGC) or POI extraction

OpenStreetMap. (Free, open source)
For RGC: Nominatim API, see the Reverse Geocoding 
For POIs and additional layers: Overpass API
Commercial APIs
Google Places API
Foursquare API

Clusters: In some cases, you would want to treat points on a map in relation to other points. Therefore, you first cluster the points and then assign the cluster ID as a categorical feature in your feature set. Some approaches:
DBSCAN, a clustering method which clusters points based on proximity/density and is robust to outliers.

GMM which is good when your clusters are relatively close to each other but you want a good separation into clusters, or when you want to create soft assignments into clusters.
Hierarchical Clustering (), which creates a dendogram of clusters and allows you to tweak the threshold which decides on the number of clusters.
Spatio-temporal approaches: In some cases, you would want to incorporate the time domain into the model as well (for example when you want to detect the stays/visits of users in a place but ignore places they visit for a very short time).

The third feature type you could extract is distances: Distance from one point to the next, distance to a fixed point (e.g., origin), it all depends on your context. The go-to distance formula is Haversine distance () which calculates a distance given that the earth is a sphere and not flat.